# jsonschema2pojo: referencing objects of the same type

Tags: java, json, jsonschema2pojo

I need to generate Java classes from a JSON schema file and came across jsonschema2pojo. However, I encountered a "problem" when using the `ref` keyword.

For example, if I use the following schema from http://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/structuring.html#extending:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
    "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  },

  "type": "object",

  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
  }
}
```

As expected, it generated a class named whatever you want to call it, containing an attribute `billingAddress` and an attribute `shippingAddress`.

However, it also generated two separate classes `BillingAddress` and `ShippingAddress` even though both attributes are referencing to `address`. Hence, I would rather have both attributes of type `Address`.

Is this possible to achieve with jsonschema2pojo?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

### Update

After getting a better understanding of javaType from [here](https://github.com/joelittlejohn/jsonschema2pojo/issues/365). I get the expected result by just adding a javaType in your Address definition.

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",

  "definitions": {
      "address": {
      "type": "object",
      "javaType": "Address",
      "properties": {
        "street_address": { "type": "string" },
        "city":           { "type": "string" },
        "state":          { "type": "string" }
      },
      "required": ["street_address", "city", "state"]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "billing_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" },
    "shipping_address": { "$ref": "#/definitions/address" }
  }
}
```

---

### Answer with two files

You need to use *javaType* in your Address.json and use *$ref* for your billing_address and shipping address. I would suggest you to separate the address definition into a separate json and then use that in your billing_address and shipping_address.

---

### Address.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/hyper-schema",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "javaType": "whatever-package-name-you-have.Address"
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
    "street_address": { "type": "string", "required":true},
    "city":           { "type": "string", "required":true },
    "state":          { "type": "string", "required":true }
  }
}
```

---

### MainClass.json

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-03/hyper-schema",
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
     "billing_address": {
           "$ref":"Address.json",
           "type": "object",
           "required": false
          },
     "shipping_address": {
           "$ref":"Address.json",
           "type": "object",
           "required": false
          }
     }
}
```